# How to input a string in regex Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to find all the occurrences of a string inside the text. The regex is working well in python console and pythex editor, but when I run the script, it does not find the string.

**Regex**

```
regex = "r'((^|\W|\s)" + keyword + "*)'"
count_list = re.findall(regex, string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

**keyword** is the input variable and value is **news**

Input **string**

```
Latest news alerts from the world. Get news by subscribing us.
```

In python console and editor, I got **two** groups. But while running script, I got **zero** as result.

I couldn't find what's wrong with the regex.

Comment: While you can construct a regex that way, it does not work for a Python expression, like a raw string.

Comment: so, what's the solution?

Comment: You have a typo in the code: `"r'((^|\W|\s)"` => `r'((^|\W|\s)'` and `"*)'"` => `"*)"`. Or even better: `r'((?:^|\W|\s)'` or `r'(\b'`

Comment: `\s` is a subset of `\W`, and it looks like you're trying to reinvent `\b` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your regex line is passing the `r''` (raw string markup) through to the regular expression parser, and I suspect that's what is making it fail.

Try changing the line to this:

```
regex = r'((^|\W|\s)' + keyword + '*)'
```

That worked for me and produced 2 groups with the output:

```
[(' news', ' '), (' news', ' ')]
```

Here is the full code I tried:

```
import re

def findthings(keyword, string):
    regex = r'((^|\W|\s)' + keyword + '*)'
    count_list = re.findall(regex, string, re.IGNORECASE)
    print(count_list)

def main():
    findthings("news", "Latest news alerts from the world. Get news by subscribing us.")
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Wiktor mentioned in comments the problem is the single quotes that are included in the regex, the following works:

```
regex = "((^|\W|\s)" + keyword + "*)"
count_list = re.findall(regex, string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

However, when dealing with strings in python I would write it using the `%` operator

```
regex = "((^|\W|\s)%s*)" % keyword
count_list = re.findall(regex, string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Finally, if you use the above regex matching in any sort of loop, I would suggest to [compile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) the string into a regex object:

```
regex_str = "((^|\W|\s)%s*)" % keyword
regex = re.compile(regex)
count_list = regex.findall(string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Hope it helps